# Why is image flashing between slides on mobile?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

First, I'm showing an error that reads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined
```

Second, as I tap through the slideshow on mobile, I'm getting a weird flash between images. I've tried to understand what the error message means, but I don't understand it. Does this mean I need to get rid of a class somewhere?

What exactly is the className that is not defined?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex += n));
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex = n));
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += "active";
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}

body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 60px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  background: white;
  
}

.title {
  line-height: 150%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 22vw;
  display: none;
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 0%;
}

.slideshow-container img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
    display: none;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  line-height: 0%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

section img {
  width: calc(100vw - 120px);
  height: calc(100vh - 120px);
}

.contain img {
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: 100% 50%;
  line-height: 0%;
  
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  top: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100vw - 120px);
  height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  
}

.next:active {
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: ;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% {opacity: 1} 
  100% {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {opacity: 1} 
  100% {opacity: 1}
}







@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  
  * {box-sizing: border-box}

body {
      padding: 0px;
}
  
  .mySlides {
    display: flex;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  height: calc(100vh - 90px);
  line-height: 0%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

section img {
  width: calc(100vw - 20px);
  height: calc(100vh - 90px);
margin: 10px;
  
  
  }
  
  .next {
  border-radius: 0;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  background: transparent;
  height: calc(100vh - 90px);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  
}
  
   .next:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }
  
  .next:active {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  .contain img {
  object-fit: contain;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    
}
  
  
}


@media only screen and (max-height: 520px) {
  body {

  }
  
  
  .slideshow-container {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 0px);
  height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 0%;
}
  
  
    .mySlides {

  max-height: calc(100vh - 0px);
  height: calc(100vh - 0px);
  line-height: 0%;
    overflow-x: hidden;

}

section img {
  width: calc(100vw - 20px);
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
margin: 10px;

  
  }
  
  .next {
  border-radius: 0;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  height: calc(100vh - 0px);
  
}
  
     .next:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }
  
  .next:active {

  }
  
  
}
```

```html
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">


  
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <section class="contain">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/226140/Screen+Shot+2020-08-09+at+2.00.17+AM.png" >
    </section>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
  
  
    <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <section class="contain">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/226140/Screen+Shot+2020-08-09+at+2.09.46+AM.png" >
    </section>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <section class="contain">
  <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/226140/Screen+Shot+2020-08-09+at+2.14.05+AM.png" alt>
</section>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  
  
  
  
  
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <section class="contain">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/226140/Screen+Shot+2020-08-09+at+2.15.57+AM.png">
    </section>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  
  
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <section class="contain">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/226140/Screen+Shot+2020-08-09+at+2.11.45+AM.png" >
    </section>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <section class="contain">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/226140/Screen+Shot+2020-08-09+at+2.12.32+AM.png" >
    </section>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <section class="contain">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/226140/Screen+Shot+2020-08-09+at+2.14.05+AM.png" >
    </section>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <section class="contain">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/226140/Screen+Shot+2020-08-09+at+2.13.40+AM.png" >
    </section>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <section class="contain">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/226140/Screen+Shot+2020-08-09+at+2.45.03+AM.png" >
    </section>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <section class="contain">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/226140/Screen+Shot+2020-08-09+at+2.12.54+AM.png" >
    </section>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <section class="contain">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/226140/Screen+Shot+2020-08-09+at+2.42.28+AM.png" >
    </section>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>


  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"></a>
</div>
<br>

<!--
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
The dots/circles -->
```

Comment: you are trying to query class that has "dot" name but  HTML element that contains className of "dot" is commented. Please debug properly at your end before asking the question.

Comment: "_I don't understand [the error message]_" The first thing to do is to learn to read error messages. There's the line number and even the column number included in the message as a link. It shouldn't be too hard to click the link and see where exactly the error occurs ...

Comment: Do you have any elements with the class name **dot**? If so, please edit them into your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the 'classname' you haven't defined is in `dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");`

Comment: yes! I tried playing with that! Any suggestions on how to resolve? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Define any variable by using ```const YourVariableNameGoeshere = YourVariablesValueGoesHere```

Comment: But I don't know what my variable should be.

Comment: If your variable is a number, you put a number there. If your variable is a boolean, it's either true or false.

Comment: I'm actually not even using the 'dots' on the front-end, is there a way to cancel them out?